# What is a good way to authenticate a user to websites and applications with a smart phone?

Tags: authentication, appsec, multi-factor, smartphone, websites

What would be a good way to authenticate a user to authenticate to websites and applications over a smart phone?  By good, I mean that it is both secure, and user-friendly.  Passwords don't seem to be the best fit because a password needs to be long to be secure, but it is hard to type a long password on a smart phone.  Some thoughts I have begun to think about are biometric measures (e.g. possibly facial recognition), and / or a token.  I asked a very similar question of authenticating a user to the smartphone itself here: [What is a good way to authenticate a user to a smart phone?](https://security.stackexchange.com/questions/81350/what-is-a-good-way-to-authenticate-a-user-to-a-smart-phone)

Comment: Same answer from me, SSO. I'm not an SSO salesperson, I promise!

Comment: What are you authenticating? I mean what is the ID you are using? In many mobile apps, by using their phone number as the ID, it is easy to authenticate their ID.

Comment: @Aron I would consider authenticating by any ID that would be easy and secure.  A phone number sounds like a great idea!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Consider [SQRL](https://www.grc.com/sqrl/sqrl.htm). It's a quite new, free, token based authentication system, using a client application. To authenticate, the client signs a cryptographic challenge with a per-domain private key. Thus it offers per-domain pseudonymity.

From Wikipedia:

> SQRL or Secure, Quick, Reliable Login (pronounced "squirrel") is a
>   draft open standard for secure website login and authentication.

Some more resources:

- [Illustrated Guide to SQRL](http://sqrl.pl/blog/)
- [Wikipedia article](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/SQRL)
- [Inventor's Website](https://www.grc.com/sqrl/sqrl.htm)

Answer (score 1):

Consider [FIDO](https://fidoalliance.org/specifications) as a standard that's being backed by [a lot of large organizations](https://fidoalliance.org/membership/members), and has already seen [deployments](http://googleonlinesecurity.blogspot.ca/2014/10/strengthening-2-step-verification-with.html).

Answer (score 1):

Authenticate using SMS is pretty typical in mobile apps.

Comment: Costly and not NSA-proof.

Comment: @AndréDaniel cheap and convenient do not make for a system that is NSA proof.